# Unable to view PDFs within Firefox on OSX

Tags: macos, firefox, adobe-reader, osx-mountain-lion, pdf-reader

I have installed the latest Adobe Reader (10.1.4) and confirmed that it works by opening a downloaded PDF document.

Unfortunately I cannot view PDFs within Firefox 15.0.1. I am just shown a blank frame. I am running Mac OSX Mountain Lion version 10.8.2.

Here is the relevant output from my `about:plugins`:
[image: about:plugins output]

#### How can I make PDFs viewable within Firefox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using the latest version of the Adobe plugin? Also, for your information, Firefox has updated since you posted and is now on version 16.0.1.

If you continue to have problems, I can suggest that you try other PDF viewers. I would personally recommend Mozilla's effort to show PDF files in-browser using web standard code. It is supposedly more secure and I find the performance to be far superior.

Install the PDF Viewer extension [here](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/pdfjs/) (safe and *official*, by Mozilla).

Comment: Thanks, that's a good albeit temporary solution. I very much doubt that it'll have good support for LaTeX built PDFs (I read a lot of academic papers)...

Comment: I disagree. The PDF spec is open and Mozilla like to follow standards. If it has no support now, they will add support for it in the near future.

In any case, I made a simple LaTeX document and exported it to PDF, then opened it in Firefox. [Here](http://i.imgur.com/IzUnM.png) is how it was rendered.

Comment: That is surprising! - Just tried opening an [academic paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1204.3370v1.pdf) in that PDF Viewer, and it all seemed to work! :O - Only problem is that Ctrl+S doesn't save it as a PDF...

Comment: The default save is set to HTML since the PDF renderer changes the code to web standard code. Manually insert ".pdf" after the file name and it should save as a PDF file.